# split screen and final render could not show objects

Tags: objects, blender-internal-render-engine

the petals show on split screen and final render.

stem and stamens only show on original screen, and not appear on slip screen and final render.
[image]

I checked the alt+h

I checked outliner panel, all camera icons checked.[image]

I checked Obeject panel[image]

Cleaned all restrict render[image]

And the stem and stamens only show on the original screen, and not appear on slip screen or final render

[image]

so here is the question: how to make the stem and stamens shows up?

thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: What is "slip screen"? What material does object have? (If any) Make sure object is placed on the scene layers which are set to be rendered in Render Layers tab in Properties editor.

Comment: Unfortunately the images are not showing any information on the active layers or the render layer settings. And the image of the outliner doesn't show all of your objects on the scene. Please **read carefully** through the answers on this page: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490). Try the proposed solutions. If you still can't solve your problem, then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to add more information, and add images that illustrate how you set up your project and settings.